# http redirection with post instead of get

Tags: apache, http, httprequest

I am getting 301 from my application to the browser :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2013 04:27:20 GMT 
Location: http://abc.com/ajax/ss 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
..............
Ez2sIJr91YfiK2eKftdb1ngLMQPr
```

`Ez2sIJr91YfiK2eKftdb1ngLMQPr1` is a encrypted body coming in 301.

After receiving browser is sending `GET` to `http://abc.com/ajax/ss`. My requirement is that browser should send `POST` instead of `GET` with  `Ez2sIJr91YfiK2eKftdb1ngLMQPr` body.

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you use status code 307.

Comment: Thanks.Its working as expected but pop has come on the browser before redirecting stating "This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend the form data you have typed to the new location?" . I don't want pop up to come. What is the way ?

Comment: You'll have to live with it for now. See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677754